# How to move the profile photo while scrolling up to the header in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, uianimation

I have an application requirement in which their is a profile picture with some personal details in it. But while scrolling the client demands that the profile photo should move to right side at the top header with animation. The android team have successfully implemented it using container layout. I got a GitHub link mimicking twitter profile animation.

[Github Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeRKQ.png)

But in that the profile photo goes underneath instead i want the profile picture to move side way at the top of the header at right side... Is there any way to achieve it?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/avadeshyadav/GmailStyleAnimation

Comment: is it available in objective c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure on how to implement it on Obj-C but the idea is, you can use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and set a state. If the user is dragging the view, move/animate the view by changing the center position. `profileImageView.center.x = ...`. Then when it scrolls up you move it again into the original position.